# Connection string works from Visual Studio, but does not work from IIS

Tags: asp.net, sqlite, iis, connection-string

I have developed a website in visual studio express for web 2013. The website pulls data from a SQLite database. This works fine in visual studio. Now I am trying to publish the website on a windows server 2008. I have setup IIS to launch the web site. However, when I launch the website from IIS, I get a Disk I/O error? 
The connnectionstring="datasource=C:....db;version=3;". Any ideas? Thanks for any help.

Comment: *"but does not work from IIS"* - on the same machine or a server you're deploying to? *" I get a Disk I/O error?*" - can you edit in the full exception you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Websites in IIS usually run under different account (LocalService). Grant permission to the file to the given account your website is running at. You can find/change the account for website in IIS -> Application pools -> select pool -> Advance Settings.

Comment: I am getting the disk i/o error while running the site as an administrator of the server. I can run the site fine from either the test machine (my own credentials) or the server itself (administrator credentials) within visual studio. When I try to launch website from IIS I get the error. If it's the connection string, I do not understand why it works from visual studio. Is the connection string relative to the current app directory?

Comment: Because in Visual Studio it runs under your account, not under LocalService. Ensure that directories have proper rights.

Comment: I just realized I was setting the Physical Path Credentials and not the App Pool Account. It's working now... Thank you for the help.

Comment: Usually I grant access for NetworkService as well to support unittest.